# How come hovering over my reputation graph in my profile shows 1 less than my actual Reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, profile-page

If I hover over the maximum point in my reputation graph my reputation displayed is `2053` where as my profile reputation shown is actually `2054` Shown below:

[image]

Why is this? Is this a bug?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: doesn't sound like it. That's a fixed bug, this is just a misunderstanding what the graph shows.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you confusing *fixed* with *"fixed"* ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was your reputation for *yesterday*. You have two events that occurred today, which gained you 1 reputation overall. But the day isn't over yet, so it doesn't show up on the reputation graph.

If you're curious, you can use the [much larger reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3578311/user1?tab=reputation) - that one will tell you the days along with the reputation number.